# How can I choose the default wx.Display in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it also possible to choose in which display a certain wx.Frame should appear in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change the default display, but this snippet creates a frame on each display.

```
import wx

def set_frame_display(frame, display_index):
    display = wx.Display(display_index)
    x, y, w, h = display.GetGeometry()
    frame.SetPosition((x, y))

def main():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    count = wx.Display_GetCount()
    for index in range(count):
        frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Display %d of %d' % (index + 1, count))
        set_frame_display(frame, index)
        frame.Center()
        frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was actually doing something similar. I just thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Just an FYI that PySimpleApp is deprecated in wx2.9. They're changing to just wx.App(False)

Comment: In newer WX apparently you need `app = wx.App(False)` and `count = wx.Display.GetCount()`.